# PS4 Controller won't stay connected

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

I'm trying to connect my DualShock 4 Controller to my Ubuntu-box. As I'm running 15.04 I have been lead to believe that this should be possible "natively".

When my controller is in pairing mode my PC can find the controller and pair just fine. However, as soon as the pairing is done the controller disconnects. If I try to turn it back on it only stays connected for a few seconds. The PC does register the controller in those few seconds though.

I've tried pairing both with PIN set to "Auto" as well as "0000" (from a tip of another forum).

I just recently upgraded to 15.04, but I had the exact same problem on 14.10.

Please let me know if you need any additional info and I'll edit it in.

Comment: Seems like it's a problem with the bluetooth chipset. Haven't been able to fix it myself but will post back if a solution is ever found.

Comment: For me it also disconnects on ubuntu 17.10. However, on the same pc it works perfectly with linux mint, so I guess it's not a chipset issue.